# multiple data sources in kendo ui dropdownlistfor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I using the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.AbcID)
            .OptionLabel("Select Abc")
            .DataTextField("AbcName")
            .DataValueField("AbcID")
            .AutoBind(true)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px" })
            .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("AutoCompleteAbcList", "Common").Data("GetSelectedXyz");
                });
            })
```

So basically what's happening is that the dropdownlist is being populated by the Json returned by the `AutoCompleteAbcList` ActionMethod.

What I'd like to know is that I have another ActionMethod `ddlPQRList` that returns a Json and I'd like to populate my dropdownlist using both the Jsons.

I have tried the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.AbcID)
            .OptionLabel("Select Abc")
            .DataTextField("AbcName")
            .DataValueField("AbcID")
            .AutoBind(true)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 300px" })
            .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("AutoCompleteAbcList", "Common").Data("GetSelectedXyz");
                    read.Action("ddlPQRList", "Common").Data("GetSelectedXyz");
                });
            })
```

but do not get the desired output. I get the list from the 2nd ActionMethod only.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible the way you are trying to do it.  A widget can only have one dataSource.

The second read Action is overwriting the first.  It is the same thing as setting a variable value twice...only the second one counts.

If you want the dataSource of the DropDownList to be the concatenation of list, then you need to create a single controller action that returns that list, i.e.:

```
read.Action("AutoCompleteAbcListANDddlPQRList", "Common").Data("GetSelectedXyz");
```

where the implementation of AutoCompleteAbcListANDddlPQRList() returns a single list of BOTH AutoCompleteAbcList and ddlPQRList lists.

Comment: aye! thank you, Cap'n. I have done exactly as you suggested. :)